# Cron running with delay

Tags: apache, cron

I'm investigating a strange issue with cron on Apache server.

Taking into account there is **no timezone set up on crontab**, I've done this test to confirm the issue.
With this two cron jobs:

```
* 7 * * * date >> /tmp/test_cron_7.txt
* 12 * * * date >> /tmp/test_cron_12.txt
```

When the server time is 12:00h PM, test_cron_7.txt is created and content of file created is "Wed Mar 15 12:00:01 UTC 2017"

Do you know what could happen and how can I fix it?

---

UPDATE:

`* * * * * echo $TZ > /tmp/test_cron` creates empty file.

`* * * * * set >/tmp/test_cron` creates a file with this content:

```
HOME='/root'
IFS='   
'
LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
LOGNAME='root'
MAILTO='root'
OPTIND='1'
PATH='/usr/bin:/bin'
PPID='21088'
PS1='# '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD='/root'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
```

`more /etc/locatime` contains:

```
TZif2
UTC0
```

Comment: Try `* * * * * echo $TZ > /tmp/test_cron` or `* * * * * set >/tmp/test_cron` to check cron's environment. and check /etc/locatime or man localtime

Comment: @DaveX I've updated question with tests that you suggested.